# Select all JSONObjects from JSONArray containing

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, arrays

I have a `JSONArray` containing `JSONObjects` like this `{firstname:'John', lastname:'Doe'}`.

Is there a way to select all `JSONObjects` having `firstname == 'John'` directly or the only way is to loop the array, test the field firstname and save all matching objects in another array?

Thanks

Comment: Please note that your question has nothing to do with JSON. JSON is just text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) should do the trick.

```js
var jsonArrayString = '[{"firstname": "John","otherProp": "otherValue"},{"firstname": "other Name", "otherProp": "otherValue"}]';

var jsonArray = JSON.parse(jsonArrayString);

var filteredArray = jsonArray.filter(function(element) {
  return element.firstname === "John";
});

console.log(filteredArray);
```

**Advice:** The filter method is not supported in <= IE 8. but there is a polyfill in the MDN article.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter them out:

```
var people = JSONArray.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.firstname == "John";
});
```

FYI: You have an *array* containing *objects*.